# Ajax disabling a popup menu plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I am using this JavaScript popup menu in my ASP.NET Web Forms project: http://jsfiddle.net/o8x59caz/4/

This code is working fine until I call a JavaScript function that contains Ajax code. And this function and the one given in the fiddle has no relation or common tags (or tag classes) between them. But whenever I call this Ajax function, it disables the popup menu and nothing happens when I click on the button that displays this popup menu. But before the control reaches this Ajax function, this popup menu is working fine. I tried to check the browser console but it shows no error or warning. Following is the code of my Ajax function:

```
var curevaldiv, ecount = 0;
function SaveAll() {
    var gifurl = '<data url of gif animation';
    var evalDivs = $("div.evld");
    if (evalDivs.length > 0) {
        evalDivs.html("<img src='" + gifurl + "' alt='Please wait. ' style='height:35px'/> <span style='font-size: medium'>Evaluating...</span>");
        var i; var infoids = '';
        for (i = 0; i < evalDivs.length; i++) {
            curevaldiv = evalDivs[i];
            infoids = infoids + curevaldiv.dataset.infoid + ';';
        }
        SendToServer(3,
           { "InfoIDs": infoids },
           null,
           function (data) {
               if (data.rstat != -1) {
                   var infoid, infoval;
                   var infovals = data.rhtml.split(';');
                   for (var j = 0; j < infovals.length; j++) {
                       infoid = infovals[j].split(':')[0];
                       infoval = infovals[j].split(':')[1];
                       $('#val' + infoid).html("<i class='fa fa-calculator'></i>&nbsp;<span class='counter'>" +
                           (infoval == "[ERROR]" ? "<font color='red'><small><i class='fa fa-exclamation-circle'></i> ERROR</small></font>" : infoval) +
                           "</span>");
                   }
                   ecount++;
               }
               else
                   curevaldiv.innerHTML = "<font color='red'><small><i class='fa fa-exclamation-circle'></i> ERROR</small></font>";
           },
                   function () {
                       curevaldiv.innerHTML = "<font color='red'><small><i class='fa fa-exclamation-circle'></i> ERROR</small></font>";
                   });
    }
}
```

`SendToServer()` is a Utility function created by me to avoid writing common Ajax parameters again and again.

Please help me! This problem is making my head heavy for past three days. :(

Comment: Is it possible that you're replacing parts of your popup menu with the results of the AJAX call?

Comment: @tvanfosson I checked it using Firefox's and IE's Inspect Element but I found no replacement in popup menu code after Ajax call.

Comment: I would try using Chrome's 'Break on > subtree modifications' to make sure the pop up menu isn't getting manipulated somehow. My first guess would be that you're breaking the DOM somehow. It's hard to tell without seeing the rest of the code.

Comment: Thanks @eck for suggesting this feature of Chrome. See my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @eck for suggesting Chrome's Break On feature. It helped me in detecting where the DOM was breaking. I traced the function call sequence and found a function that was making the HTML of the `div` containing the popup menu's HTML to `null` and then again resetting it back to the popup menu's HTML. But the plugin was called on previous popup menu's HTML. I removed that code and now it's working fine. :)